# How to iterate through parent objects and change inherited object properties in Java

Tags: java, android, inheritance, iterator

I am trying to iterate through an object that I have created and change some of its properties by using a get/set method. I managed to make it work when I only had one object, but now I have objects that inherit the parent object and each have slightly different properties that I want to change. E.g. a String, Float, Integer, Double object. At runtime I will not know which object will be found, so I want my Android application to be able to find it via a unique address and change the properties in the specific inherited object by iterating through the parent object. Please help me with this problem if anyone can. Thank you in advance.

Here is the parent object class code:

```
public class DataObject 
{
private byte[] address;
private String type;
private boolean updatedFlag;
private boolean editedFlag;

public DataObject() 
{   
    updatedFlag = false;
    editedFlag = false;
}

public void setAddress(byte[] address)
{
    this.address = address;
}

public void setType(String type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

public void setUpdatedFlag(boolean updatedFlag)
{
    this.updatedFlag = updatedFlag;
}

public void setEditedFlag(boolean editedFlag)
{
    this.editedFlag = editedFlag;
}

public byte[] getAddress()
{   
    //return Arrays.toString(address);
    return address;
}

public String getType()
{
    return type;
}

public boolean getUpdatedFlag()
{
    return updatedFlag;
}

public boolean getEditedFlag()
{
    return editedFlag;
}
}
```

Here is one of the inherited object class:

```
public class DoubleDataObject extends DataObject
{
private double value;
private String range;

public DoubleDataObject() 
{

}

public void setValue(double value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public void setRange(String range)
{
    this.range = range;
}

public double getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public String getRange()
{
    return range;
}
}
```

And here is the code that iterates through the objects to change their properties:

```
private void setUpValues(byte[] address, byte[] value)
{   
    byte[] addressByteArray = address;

    Iterator<DataObject> it = dataObjects.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        DataObject currentDataObject = it.next();
        byte[] dataObjectByteArray = currentDataObject.getAddress();
        if(addressByteArray[0] == dataObjectByteArray[0])
        {
            System.out.println("Found subsystem!");

            if(addressByteArray[1] == dataObjectByteArray[1])
            {
                System.out.println("Found highlevel!");

                if(addressByteArray[2] == dataObjectByteArray[2])
                {
                    System.out.println("Found low level!");
                    System.out.println("Found data object!");

                    currentDataObject.setValue(value);
                    currentDataObject.setUpdatedFlag(true);

                    System.out.println("Data Object Address: " + Arrays.toString(currentDataObject.getAddress()));
                    System.out.println("Data Object Type: " + currentDataObject.getType());
                    System.out.println("Data Object Value: " + currentDataObject.getValue());
                    System.out.println("Data Object Range: " + currentDataObject.getRange());
                    System.out.println("Data Object Updated Flag: " + currentDataObject.getUpdatedFlag());
                    System.out.println("Data Object Edited Flag: " + currentDataObject.getEditedFlag());
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("CANNOT FIND DATA OBJECT!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("CANNOT FIND HIGH LEVEL!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("CANNOT FIND SUBSYSTEM!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define 'parent object'.

Comment: DataObject is what I mean by the parent object and the other objects inherit the DataObject's properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which class an object is and cast it to the subclass to access the methods,
is that waht you want to achieve?

```
    DataObject currentDataObject = it.next();
if(currentDataObject instanceof DoubleDataObject){
 DoubleDataObject doubleData = (DoubleDataObject) currentDataObject;
//check your methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
if (currentDataObject.getClass().equals(DoubleDataObject.class)) {
DoubleDataObject currentDoubleDataObject = (DoubleDataObject)currentDataObject;
currentDoubleDataObject .setValue(1.4d);
}
```

To test if the currentDataObject is a DoubleDataObject (and not a class inherit from a DoubleDataObject )

Comment: I have four inherited data objects though. String, Int, Float and Double. Won't this end up being a lot of code, because I will have to do an if statement for each DataObject or will it not matter too much? Thank you for your answer.